# How to automatically convert a date to a specific text string?

Tags: excel

I need to automatically convert in Excel a date to a specific string based on month and year.

Date to be converted ........... String to be changed to:

30-12-2018 06:00:00 PM ..... 12-December 18

29-12-2018 06:00:00 PM ..... 12-December 18

28-12-2018 06:00:00 PM ..... 12-December 18

30-11-2018 06:00:00 PM ..... 11-November 18

29-11-2018 06:00:00 PM ..... 11-November 18

Presented dates are provided for example purposes.

Do you know any solution to make this automatic?

I have already tried creating a separate sheet in the workbook where I manually wrote the association between the date and the string. Then I used VLOOKUP to bring the string to the area where I want to change the date.

But I want to send this report to end users and I don't want them to need to add new dates each time. Rather I want the file to update itself if possible.

[image: Date Correspondence Sheet]

[image: Report with VLOOKUP to Date Correspondence Sheet]

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Technically speaking, your examples are **very confusing**.  i.e.: 30-11-2018 = 11-October 18?  Is that right?  Don't you mean 30-October 18?  All of them appear to have this 'issue,' unless its truly intentional (which would surprise me).

Comment: Sorry. It's not intentional to create confusion. In a simpler statement I need to tell Excel that, for example, all dates between 01-11-2018 and 30-11-2018 need to be converted to the following text 11-November 18 (not October, sorry I will correct).

Comment: I already did this by creating an additional Sheet where I made the connexion manually (i.e. by adding 11-November 18 next to each date) and then used VLOOKUP in the other Sheet to change them there. But for 2019 the end user would need to do this and I am trying to simplify his:her life a bit. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In the cell formatting settings, you can use the custom date format string `dd-mmmm yy` for this. In my opinion, though, you'd be better off setting the cell's format to display dates according to the user's system settings.

I'm also assuming here that `30-12-2018 06:00:00 PM` is a representation of a valid date value in Excel, rather than a free-text string. If not, then your actual problem is parsing this value as a date rather than displaying it in another format.

Comment: Thank you for your answear! I forgot to specify one important thing.
I am updating the question above.

Comment: Yes, I know about Format text. This is different, albeit I did not ask the question correctly at first. I have changed it to reflect what I need. Thank you!

Comment: Still not quite clear. Can you confirm that the cell that's displaying `30-12-2018 06:00:00 PM` contains a date, and not just a string representing a date - i.e. if you add 1 to it, do you get `31-12-2018 06:00:00 PM` or `#VALUE!`?

Comment: It is a Custom field, type dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm. To be more clear I added images of what I am trying to do (I did not see you could add images to the question). So we have the Date Correspondence Sheet. Here I have put manually the correspondance between the date and the month indicator (this is what I use 12-December 18 for all dates and hours in December 2018, written manually, by hand). Then we have the Report with VLOOKUP to Date Correspondence Sheet where I need to convert the date from the Created Date column to the date from the Created Month column.

Comment: I can do this with VLOOKUP since I already have the same key in the two sheets. But for a date that is not in the Date Correspondence Sheet it does not work until I add it manually in that Sheet, which I can do, but I am intersted to make it automated. If possible. Maybe VBA, but I am completly blank on VBA knowledge :(.

Comment: So `12-December` should be read as the month of December referred to by both number and name (and not the 12th of December as I previously thought)? In that case, a format string of `mm-mmmm yy` will format it this way.